# How do I get MapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true) to work?

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

I'm trying to create a MapView with built-in zoom controllers, here's the code:

```
MapView mMapView;
mMapView=new MapView(this, GMAPS_API_KEY);
mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mMapView.setSatellite(false);
mMapView.getController().setZoom(16);
someView.addView(mMapView);
```

The map works fine; I've also added a MyLocationOverlay on it and it works fine. However, the zoom controls do NOT show up. The call to setBuiltInZoomControls(true) is completely ignored. No error message is logged.

What may I be missing that is needed to have setBuiltInZoomControls work as expected?

Yes, my activity extends MapActivity.

Comment: I'm realising that it's not just the zoom controls not working. The whole map view is crippled: (1) moving the finger on it it does not move; (2) the MyLocatioOverlay does not show up immediately but only after a several seconds (at the first update, I guess), even if the location _is_ available from the very beginning.  All tutorials and examples I have found around about MapView assume you are just putting a mapview node in an xml layout and inflating it with setContentLayout. However the documentation does not say anywhere that that is the only way MapView is supposed to work...

Comment: can anybody point me to any example of creating a MapView programmatically and adding it to existing views? I've already managed that, but as I said the map is far from fully functional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mMapView.setClickable(true);
```

I just ran into this myself and it's how I eventually solved it (though I did it with an XML attribute instead of within the Activity code).

Comment: This solved all the problems, except the fat that the MyLocationOverlay doesn't show up until several seconds later (though the location _is_ available since the beginning). I ended up creating an activity only for the map, with the MapView in the xml layout, as in the examples, and it works like a charm. If MapView can't be created programmatically and added to existing views, they should specify it in the documentation so developers wouldn't waste their time trying something that seems perfectly reasonable.